# Magento2 how to make query in the right method?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, database, sql, zend-framework

I have created ***a sql query*** but `i don't know how` to make this as in the Magento2 format any help

```
$sql = "`select product_id,customer_Id,bid_status,MAX(bid_Amount) max_bid FROM mbid_history as d where customer_id in(select max(customer_id) from mbid_history as m where m.product_id=d.product_id) AND bid_status=1 group by product_id,customer_id,bid_status`";
```

I have tried this but it is returns wrong data

```
$sql = $connection->select()
            ->from(
                ['o' => $tableName],
                ['MAX(bid_amount) as max_bid', 'product_id', 'customer_id']

            )->where('o.bid_status=?', '1')
            ->group('product_id', 'customer_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, But i am not sure about it:

> ```
> $connection = $this->getConnection();
>
>   $subSelect = $connection->select()->from(
>     ['m' => 'mbid_history'],
>     [ new \Zend_Db_Expr('MAX(customer_id)')]
> )->where(
>     'm.product_id = d.product_id'
> );
>
> $select = $connection->select()->from(
>     'd' =>'mbid_history',
>     ['max_bid' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('MAX(bid_Amount)'), 'product_id', 'customer_Id','bid_status']
> )->where('bid_status=?', '1'
>
> )->where('customer_id IN (?)', new \Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('(%s)', $subSelect->assemble())))
>
> ->group(
>     ['product_id', 'customer_id' ,'bid_status']
> );
> ```

Comment: Tried this but not working.